# Not able to find MarkerView in MapBox

Tags: react-native, maps, mapbox-gl-js

I'm not able to find markerview in MapBox in this github library
https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps, So can anyone help me please?

Or else I'm using PointAnnotation in it like this,

```
               <MapboxGL.MapView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <MapboxGL.Camera centerCoordinate={[22.470701, 70.057732]} zoomLevel={14} >

                        </MapboxGL.Camera>
                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                            id="foo1"
                            coordinate={[22.470701, 70.057732]}
                            title={'Hello'}>
                            <View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
                                <Image source={require('./chat.png')} style={styles.tinyLogo} />
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', margin: 10 }}>$50.00</Text>
                            </View>
                            <MapboxGL.Callout style={{ borderRadius: 20, width: 150, height: 120 }}>
                                <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                    <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 10 }}>123, Main st,</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>Chicago, IL 6061</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', margin: 10, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <Text style={{ margin: 10, color: 'white' }}>Select Shop</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </MapboxGL.Callout>
                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>   
             </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

But that image is not showing, so can anyone help me with what should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of MarkerView usage is available [here](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/MarkerView.js)
The MarkerView documentation is available [here](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MarkerView.md)

*From this documentation*

> If you have static view consider using PointAnnotation or SymbolLayer they'll offer much better performance

So if you are in this case, it seems that you're doing good.

Comment: I want to open a pop up dialog on click of the marker that has been shown to user, so how to do that?

Comment: Please help me with this @behelit